# Facebook profile subscription settings: What types of updates are considered 'Other Activity'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-subscriptions

Facebook allows you to choose which types of updates from a friend's profile you'd like to subscribe to:

[image]

There is an option for 'Other Activity'. What types of updates are considered 'Other Activity'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This includes a lot of miscellaneous things that may appear in the News Feed but do not fit in the other categories, such as the person posting to or being added to a group, attending an event, getting new Facebook friends, changing their profile information, being tagged in a non-photo post, or anything from one of their Facebook apps that is not classified as a game/music/video, including cross posts from other networks using e.g. the Twitter/Tumblr/Pinterest apps.

If you're not sure how a particular post about a friend is classified, just press the little `v` icon that appears in the upper right corner of the post when you hover over it in your main News Feed.  If it shows the option "Unsubscribe from activity stories by **__**", then it is Other Activity.